# Freeware which allows to copy multiple times then paste multiple times in same order

Tags: clipboard

I want to copy a link to clipboard, then copy title, then copy excerpt then paste 3 times in same order in a document.

Do you know any freeware that can do so ?

Comment: @Dennis if they don't specify OS, it's Windows. Because there can be nothing else *sigh*

Comment: @Daniel: *sigh*, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://m8software.com/clipboards/freeclip/freeclip.htm

---

Edit:

After installation run the FreeClip program.

- On the `Tools` menu select `Options`
- Choose a keyboard shortcut such as `F8`, select `Alt` as a modifier
- On the `View` menu select (tick the box) `keyboard pasting characters`
- minimise FreeClip

Cut your link, title and excerpt in the usual way - for example by selecting the text and pressing Ctrl+C

To paste the link, title and excerpt press `Alt+F8 C` then `Alt+F8 B` then `Alt+F8 A`

If you move focus from FreeClip back to the document you are editing then you'll have to switch focus back to Freeclip using `ALt+F8` before pressing `A`, `B` or `C`.

You can do all the above just by using the mouse if you prefer that to keyboard shortcuts.

If you want a program that deletes an item from the clipboard when pasting or which , after a paste, moves a current pointer to an older cut item - this program isn't the one for you.

Comment: I have tried it, I can copy multiple times but I cannot see how to paste multiple times.

Comment: "When you want to paste one back, all you have to do is restore M8 and **click on the clip you want**. If you prefer to work entirely from the keyboard, you can choose a hot key to restore M8 and then paste any clip by typing the letter shown next to it."

Comment: Wow thank you very much for such detailed instructions :)